# Access control for cross site requests in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, access-control

I am trying to make an AJAX call from several domains to a single one which will handle the request. Enabling Cross domain in Firefox and Chrome was easy by setting the header on the handling server:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

But this doesn't help enabling it in Internet Explorer. When I try:

```
httpreq.send('');
```

it stops with error Access denied.

How can this be enabled in Internet Explorer?

Comment: IE 10 work fine, IE8/9 with limitation. See http://caniuse.com/#search=cors

Comment: What are the specific limitations of CORS support in IE9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that directly in Internet Explorer. You have a couple of options:

- Set up a proxy forwarding script on the server you do control that can forward the Ajax requests. Make sure that it only forwards to the appropriate destinations that you need so that you don't get turned into an anonymous relay.
- Use the `document.domain` trick. Basically you need to create a set of `iframe`s, one for each server you need to make Ajax calls to. Within each `iframe` set the `document.domain` property to exactly match the domain you need to send the Ajax requests *to*. As to how to populate the necessary data, use DOM manipulation prior to setting `document.domain`. Note that this trick requires the target servers to be in sub-domains of the original. More in [this article](http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/), with examples.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I've done it with proxy script on server.

Answer (score 12):

Much has changed since I first posted my solution for CORS in IE7 and above. First of all the jQuery property $.support.cors is true by default, .NET frameworks 4.0 and above no longer support CORS as implemented in versions 3.5.1 and lower. When writing a web service with ASP.NET 4.0 I had install the Thinktecture.IdentityModel which is available as a NuGet package. Then, in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax file, add:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http.Cors.IIS.UrlBasedCorsConfiguration.Configuration
        .ForResources("*")
        .ForOrigins("http://localhost:80, http://mydomain")
        .AllowAll()
        .AllowMethods("GET", "POST");
}
```

Now add the httpProtocol element within system.webServer:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, X-File-Name" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

My $.ajax call is now:

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl, 
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
});
```

Comment: When this question was first posted IE 6 and 7 were still very common, and they have no CORS support at all. I don't believe `$.support.cors` had been implemented then either. Good to know things have improved!

Comment: from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/ "...cors is equal to true if a browser can create an XMLHttpRequest object and if that XMLHttpRequest object has a withCredentials property. To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set $.support.cors = true;...". I've verified this works in IE7, IE8, and IE9.

Comment: This is great but doesnt work in IE8. This one here https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest is very useful and it works in all browsers including IE8 ( haven't tested in IE 7 )
Credits to @gbakernet

Comment: Thank you for the response Srikanth. This solution did work in IE8 for our users. There may be other variables affecting your implementation. Much has changed since this solution was posted. $.support.cors is true by default in all later versions of jQuery and this approach no longer works with .Net framework 4 and above. You must now include a library such as the Thinktecture.IdentityModel.dll for CORS to work with a .Net service. CORS must be enabled in the Global.asax method Application_Start

Answer (score 10):

Did you try do enable **Access Data Source Cross Domains**
[image]

Comment: it was useful for testing the website on localhost:8080

Comment: Work like a charm. Really useful to test on localhost +1

Answer (score 3):

I got IE8 and 9 working with just jQuery $.ajax (jQuery version 1.7.2)

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
jQuery(function() {
$.ajax({
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType: 'html',
    //...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For Internet Explorer 8, you need to do like for FF3, ie use the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header plus use XDomainRequest object instead of XMLHttpRequest.
Everything is explaiend in detail here for IE8:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28VS.85%29.aspx

Older flavours of IE don't support Cross Site Access Control nor XDomainRequest objects.
However it's not over, you could resort to the IFrame trick for instance, ie creating an invisible IFrame that calls your functions as described here:
http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the Eric's answer , for Older version of IE , you can use Jquery 1.4.2's $.ajax method , that by default allows the cross domain requests, or for cross domain JSON , you can use

**jQuery.getJSON( String url, Map data, Function callback ) returns XMLHttpRequest**

An Excerpt from Jquery docs.

"jQuery now supports JSONP natively - if you attempt to load JSON (via $.getJSON or $.ajax) from a remote URL then an extra callback will be provided for the server to interpret."

Comment: To clarify, this *only* works for jsonp requests. jQuery does not provide support for XDomainRequest, and the workarounds that do require jQuery 1.5 or later: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283