# Crossdomain ajax with xml file IE

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I've built a script to use jquery's ajax function to pull an xml file crossdomain. The xml file is an rss feed for itunes. In the php that creates the xml file I've added this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I've looked into the issue and it works in all browsers except IE. Supposedly it works in 10, but I've only tested 9. I've looked online and found that maybe I can hack together a XDomainRequest, but it wasn't very stable and had quite a few limitations, making me think it's not worth it.

If there is no way to get around this for IE 9 and below then I will simply put a feature detection and recommend the user update to ie 10 or download another browser.

Does anyone know of stable way to pull xml crossdomain in IE 9 and below?

Comment: does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11018603/2055808

Comment: My concern is that itunes is pulling the same feed. I suppose I can add something to check if it's a jsonp request though in the php. Would it for sure work with IE 9?

Comment: Imortenson, I've tried the jquery.support.cors = true, but I've never seen that web.config thing. Where would I find this web.config file to add the headers? It's a linux server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having recently gone through this myself, I found the following jQuery plugin worked well:

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

The API works seamlessly with regular jQuery ajax and I only pull in the script if IE8 or IE9 (via requirejs).

A couple of things to remember with XDomainRequest

- Cannot set custom headers (so if you are passing around data has to be query string)
- Cannot cross secure boundaries (i.e., cannot go from HTTPS to HTTP)

Other than those two points above, I have had no issues and the code has been running in Production for a few weeks.

Comment: Yeah it works, it's acting a bit weird but I think I can figure it out from here. It pulled it.